# Are Wordpress Gravity Forms able to make REST API calls to get/send data from a 3rd party site that has an exposed REST API

Tags: json, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WordPress for a new site created by the GoDaddy team for time and ease. The administrator I am using for my products requires REST API integration. Does anyone know if WordPress Gravity forms are able to make REST API calls to get and send data from a 3rd party site that has an Exposed REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I am unrelated to these two products but I have found them to work for occasions when I need a Gravity From to submit to a remote API during submission.

- Paid option (I use this primarily) https://vanrossum.dev/products/gf-send-to-api with an improved feed option with custom field and response mapping https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx2Vbit0sEA
- Free option https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-post-to-3rd-party/